# how to install moztrap on windows 8.1?

Tags: python, windows, testcase

I want to install moztrap locally on my pc. As a reference, I use https://moztrap.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.6/installation.html.

Environment:

- OS windows 8.1 x64 professional
- XAMPP
- Visual Studio 2013 x64 express
- Python 3.4.1
- Installation directory: `c:\xampp\htdocs\moztrap`

> 1- git clone --recursive git://github.com/mozilla/moztrap
>
> 2- cd moztrap
>
> 3- mkvirtualenv moztrap

These three steps are OK. But I cannot get the 4 step onward working.

> 4- bin/install-reqs

I get the following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\moztrap>bin/install-reqs

'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

`install=-reqs` can be found https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/moztrap/master/bin/install-reqs'>here.

So can anyone help me with this? (I need to mention I do not know python, or else this might be so easy!)

Comment: I Found 3 things: 1. I need to say "python bin/install-reqs", 2. Moztrap is not compatible with Python 3, python 2 should be used. 3. It needs VS 2008, not VS 20013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple solutions, I got the followings steps to work (note that we are using this https://moztrap.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.6/installation.html'>doc as reference):

```
1- git clone --recursive git://github.com/mozilla/moztrap
```

You may you need to change the protocol from `git` to `http` if you are behind a firewall that does not allow `git` protocol. Also you need to git the submodules also with `http` in this case.

```
2- cd moztrap

3- mkvirtualenv moztrap
```

These steps are OK.

For **step 4** there are some issues using the given default command `4- bin/install-reqs`. There are few requirements mentioned in `\requirements\compiled.txt` that are `C` libraries and need compilation. I faced following issues:

- It needs a Visual Studio 2008 for compilation
- Even after installation of VS 2008, there are problems compling the packages all together.

So I chose to first install the compiled packages one by one, and then install without complied dependencies`install-reqs pure`. So before that:

- Get the `.exe` file for **MySQL-python** from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4'>here
- Use `pip install py-bcrypt-w32` (also needs VS 2008 for compilation), installing `pip install py-bcrypt` did NOT work.

  `4- python bin\install-reqs pure`

Then:

Create `moztrap\settings\local.py` and enter the database credentials (you can make a copy of `local.sample.py` then uncomment the database part). Then:

```
5- echo "CREATE DATABASE moztrap CHARACTER SET utf8" | c:\xampp\bin\mysql

6- python manage.py syncdb --migrate

7- python manage.py create_default_roles

8- python manage.py runserver
```

And now you can visit `http://localhost:8000` in your browser and that is it! You are done!

---

Please remember that you need:

- Visual Studio 2008, the later versions cause problems during insatallation
- Use Python 2.7, Python 3 causes problems during insatallation